# Qt4 - QDir::entryList() doesn't return files/dirs with invalid encoding

Tags: utf-8, qt4

My Qt4-based application (http://qcomicbook.linux-projects.net) has a problem with opening files located in directories with invalid encoding (most likely koi-8 encoding, or some other Asian encoding). The problem occurs in the following piece of code:

```
QDir dir(path);
dir.setSorting(flags);
dir.setFilter(QDir::AllDirs|QDir::Files);

const QStringList files = dir.entryList();
foreach (QString f, files) {
 ...
}
```

If path includes dirs/files with invalid encoding, then dir.entryList() just filters them out. The problem is also indicated by QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory dialog which displays "invalid encoding" warning along file dir names.

Is there any workaround for this, ideally transparent to the end user?